# Geoserver SLD: setting fill color from property does not work

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

I'm trying to style a vector (Point) Layer in Geoserver 2.8 by using a property (attribute field) of the underlying  data source.
Here's the snippet:

```
<PointSymbolizer>
        <Graphic>
          <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">
                <ogc:PropertyName>HEXCOLOR</ogc:PropertyName>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
                1
              </CssParameter>
            </Fill>
          </Mark>
        </Graphic>
</PointSymbolizer>
```

Where *HEXCOLOR* is a string like #fff000.
However, the point is rendered with white filling.

I have so far checked

- the data (Q-GIS is able to render the color definitions)
- the syntax

Comment: Try with fill-opacity = 1.0

Comment: I'd suggest to ask on geoserver-users, sharing a link to a data sample and full style.

Comment: Do you really need the `<ogc:PropertyName>...`? For a polygonSymbolizer the following works for me: `<sld:CssParameter name="fill">#FFCCB3</sld:CssParameter>`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with that method, however you may use [rule based styling](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/rules.html) for symbolizing various feature classifications:

> Styling rules define the portrayal of features. A rule combines a
>   filter with any number of symbolizers. Features for which the filter
>   condition evaluates as true are rendered using the the symbolizers in
>   the rule.